# Idiomatic use of implicit unwrapping in Swift

Tags: swift, conditional-statements, option-type

In the Bloc ["Swiftris" Swift tutorial (step 5)](https://www.bloc.io/tutorials/swiftris-build-your-first-ios-game-with-swift#!/chapters/680) we are asked to write

```
var tick:(() -> ())?
var tickLengthMillis = TickLengthLevelOne
var lastTick:NSDate?

override func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {
    if lastTick == nil {
        return
    }
    var timePassed = lastTick!.timeIntervalSinceNow * -1000.0
    if timePassed > tickLengthMillis {
        lastTick = NSDate.date()
        tick?()
    }
}
```

Couldn't the body of `update` have been written as

```
if let timePassed = lastTick?.timeIntervalSinceNow {
    if timePassed * -1000.0 > tickLengthMillis {
          lastTick = NSDate.date()
          tick?()
    }
}
```

with the same effect.

If so, why does the more compact and apparently (to me) equivalent

```
if lastTick?.timeIntervalSinceNow * -1000.0 > tickLengthMillis {
    lastTick = NSDate.date()
    tick?()
}
```

fail (with "value of optional type Double? not unwrapped")?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because if `lastTick` is `nil`, the compiler wouldn't know how to handle this expression:

```
nil * -1000.0
```

So a non optional value must be used.

It works in the first case:

```
if lastTick == nil {
    return
}
var timePassed = lastTick!.timeIntervalSinceNow * -1000.0
```

because `timePassed` is not an optional (here using the forced unwrapping is safe thanks to the preceding `if` check).

It also works in the second case:

```
if let timePassed = lastTick?.timeIntervalSinceNow {
```

because optional binding ensure that the `if` branch is executed only if the expression at the right side evaluates to a non-nil value

Comment: I don't think that's true. If `lastTick` is `nil` , `lastTick?.timeIntervalSinceNow` evaluates to `nil`, but omitting the `* -1000.0` produces no error (the `>` works); so the issue is the `*` operation, I think.

Comment: correct, because you'd have ```if nil * -1000.0 > tickLengthMillis```, but the value of ```nil * -1000.0``` can not be determined, see [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26166511/2147244) above for more details

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius yes, that's correct, my mistake - but the source of error is still the same: `lastTick` being an optional. Thanks for spotting the error, I've updated my answer accordingly

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that `if` must have a condition to test, but it doesn't in case if the optional is empty.

Let's take your if-statement:

```
if lastTick?.timeIntervalSinceNow * -1000.0 > tickLengthMillis {
   lastTick = NSDate.date()
   tick?()
}
```

There exist two possibilities:

1. `lastTick` has a value - if-statement can then be rewritten to `if a > b`
2. `lastTick` is empty - if-statement would make no sense as it would be `if ??? > b` and I imagine that behavior is undetermined.

The compiler tries to be on the safe side and emits the error.

**UPDATE**

`if lastTick?.timeIntervalSinceNow * -1000.0 > tickLengthMillis`

in case when `lastTick?` is empty can be rewritten as

`if nil * -1000.0 > tickLengthMillis`

where the value of `nil * -1000.0` is undetermined.

Comment: How about the first version? That's equivalent to the original, right?

Comment: Looks equivalent to me. The difference between #1 and #2 is that you first unpack the optional ```if let timePassed = lastTick?.timeIntervalSinceNow``` and then you're safe to work with it.